# printing xml post request sent to local host on web page using php

Tags: php, xml

I am currently sending an XML post request to my localhost. I want the request to be printed on my localhost/Tesst.php web page. I have tried this:

```
if(!isset($_POST) || empty($_POST)) { 
        header("Refresh:0");
    } else { 
        $_any= file_get_contents("php://input");
        echo $_any;
    }
```

but the page kept on refreshing all the time and it didn't post anything. Is there a way to print the request on the web page?

**Edit**: 
I am using this code in C# to send the data:

```
string post_data = @" OTA_request=<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><OTA_HotelAvailRQ xmlns=""http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xsi:schemaLocation=""http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05 OTA_HotelAvailRQ.xsd"" Version=""1.006"" PrimaryLangID=""it"" Target=""Test""><POS><Source><RequestorID ID=""71838"" MessagePassword=""1234657"" Type=""10"" /></Source></POS><AvailRequestSegments><AvailRequestSegment><HotelSearchCriteria><Criterion><StayDateRange Start=""2019-02-18"" End=""2019-02-27""/><HotelRef HotelCode=""37190""/></Criterion></HotelSearchCriteria></AvailRequestSegment></AvailRequestSegments></OTA_HotelAvailRQ>"
     string uri = "http://localhost/Tesst.php";

                // create a request
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
                WebRequest.Create(uri); request.KeepAlive = false;
                request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
                request.Method = "POST";
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new MyPolicy();
                // turn our request string into a byte stream
                byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post_data);

                // this is important - make sure you specify type this way
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
                Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

                // now send it
                requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
                requestStream.Close();

                // grab the response and print it out to the console along with the status code
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: Obviously you will never see the second part of your code, because your logic does not have any openings for that.

Usually when the POST is not setter or empty, you should check about other conditions before refresh the page. The major problem in your question is that you are not showing to us how you're sending your xml to your php file

Comment: can you add your POST data here.

Comment: I have edited my code for you to see how i'm sending the request.

Answer (score 0):

PHP only populates `$_POST`, if the `Content-Type` of the request was `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

Check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` instead to figure out whether you are dealing with a POST request or not.

Comment: Please view the code, i have edited it and shown how i'm sending the data

Comment: Try and remove the ContentLength (for testing) - if you get that wrong, the parser is likely not going to populate $_POST either. Remove the if/else stuff for now, and check what $any actually contains then.

Comment: I have removed them, $any still haven't posted anything on the web page. The thing is I'm getting the XML request printed in the cmd it is just not being posted on the web page

Comment: Well then that rather sounds like a problem on the sending side to begin with - so I’d suggest some additional research, how to make proper HTTP POST requests in C#, and what possible cave-ats might need paying attention to.

Comment: I have previously used this to send HTTP POST requests to a proper page and everything worked fine. And I have used this to send to webhook.site and it worked just fine and everything appeared properly. I just want the request to appear on my page the way they appear on webhook.site